# wierd error : code get executed more than once per click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have a like comments system

when i click on the like link sometimes it works fine but some times it sends up to 8-9 request per click ! i have the same problem on another jquery code which works with keydown event

```
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="like_comment" ><?php echo $likeLable; ?></a>



 $('.like_comment').live('click', function () {
     var parent = $(this).parent();
     var comment_id = parent.parent().find('.comment_id').val();
     parent.fadeOut(200);

     $.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>album/like", {
         comment_id: comment_id
     },
     function (data) {
         if ($.trim(data) == 'ok') {
             var like_span = parent.parent().find('.like_counter');
             var like = parseInt(like_span.text()) + 1;
             like_span.text(like);

             parent.html('<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="unlike_comment" ><?php echo $unlikeLable; ?></a>');
             parent.fadeIn(200);
             return false;
         } else {
             parent.fadeIn(200);
             alert(data);
         }
     })
 })
```

is there anything wrong with this code ?

Answer (score 2):

Try returning `true` from the event handler to signify that you handled the event.  That way noone else will pick it up...

If that doesn't work, then you are probably registering multiple event listeners for the same event.  Use your favorite debugger to pause javascript execution, then use the console to inspect all the event listeners on the relevant dom elements.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to know without seeing the rest of your code and know what element the click is applied to, so one of the following 3 solutions could work:

```
$('.like_comment').on('click',function(e) {
     //do something
     e.preventDefault();     // stops default button action, e.g. submitting a form
     e.stopPropagation();    // stops event bubbling back to parent element
   }  
   return false;         /// stops default link action
});
```

Also as a by-the-way, live is now deprecated and has been replaced by "on" instead.